# how to split off first "column" of a php associative array of strings into a simple array of strings

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using this to to retrieve two columns in a database

```
   while($comment[]=mysql_fetch_array($sql));
```

this returns an array with associative and number indices for each column.
This works great but I would also like to create a new array from the  orginial`$comment[]` that is just a simple array of strings (only the first column). What are my options? Is there any way to accomplish this without looping through a second time?

Comment: You might not want to do the array assignment within the while loop like that. It creates a phantom empty record as the last array element when you reach the end of the record set (the 'false' returned by the fetch call when there's no more data). Better to do `while($row = fetch()) { $comment[] = $row }` type thing instead.

Comment: It seems like a waste of memory to store redundant data.  How about calling `array_column()` ...if you must.  Additionally, do you need the array bloat of indexed and associaitve keys in your `$comments` array?  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how many columns you have, you could do something like:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while (list($col1[], $col2[]) = mysql_fetch_row($result));
```

`$col1` will be an array of just column 1's values, and `$col2` will be similar for column 2's values.

Comment: It seems unfortunate that all of the solutions involve looping through the entire array a second time. I'd rather not loop through my data twice...

Comment: If you don't want to loop through twice, don't create the $col1 and $col2 arrays, simply do while (list($val1, $val2) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { ... }  The question specifically asked to create two arrays.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array();
for ($i = 0;$comment = mysql_fetch_array($sql);$i++){
    $array[$i] = $comment['field_name'];
}
```